# 一致する値すべてのindexを取得するコードの内容がわかりません

Tags: python

一致する値すべてのindexを取得する単元を学習しております。[image: listから1をindexする。]

listから1をindexする問題となっており、解説では上記のコードが記載されておりました。
私の勉強不足ですが、コードの中の「i for i」の部分がどのような意味を示し、どのような処理をするか不明となっております。
分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: "内包表記"で調べると情報が見つかるかと思います。「単元を学習しております」「解説では上記のコードが記載」とのことですが、事前に内包表記について説明はなかったですか？

Comment: 初めて聞いた名前なので、調べてみます。

Comment: 調べて、コードの内容を確認しました。

Comment: 要素(x)が１の場合のインデック番号が取り出され、forの後ろのiに代入。最後に取り出されたインデックス番号が先頭のiに代入される。というコードの動きで認識して良いでしょうか？

Comment: 内包表記が初めての場合にはforループで書き直すと理解が深まるかと思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます.

Comment: 上記の内装表記もforループに書き直すのはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: [5.1.3. List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: 無事、for文のコードを書く事ができました。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。いただいた資料でも勉強します！

Comment: **念の為**: "○○ comprehensions" の和訳として「○○内包表記」という用語が用いられます。
リスト(の)内包表記, リスト内包, set内包, 辞書内包表記 など (習うなら (そのままの)「内包表記」ではないでしょう)。また同様の表記として "generator expression" というのもあります ("comprehensions" の単語は出てこない)。

Comment: ありがとうございます!

Answer (score 1):

> コードの中の「i for i」の部分がどのような意味を示し、どのような処理をするか不明となっております。

簡単なコードで説明します。

```
result = [i for i in [1,2,3]]
print(result)
# [1, 2, 3]
```

上記ではリスト[1,2,3]から要素を1つずつ取り出してiに格納しています。そしてiをそのまま新たなリストの要素としています。

例えば取り出した要素を2倍にしたい場合は下記コードにすれば良いです。

```
result = [i*2 for i in [1,2,3]]
print(result)
# [2, 4, 6]
```

1点指摘ですが、質問のコードでは変数名に`list`を使われていますがこれはPythonの組み込み型のため変数名に使うのは止めましょう。

Comment: わかりやすい。解説ありがとうございます。無事解決できました。